# Serialize objects with relationships to json format | Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

My models:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 44, unique = True)
    course_class = models.OneToOneField('courses.Class', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ExamQuestion(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    multiple_choice = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Reply(models.Model):
    exam_question = models.OneToOneField(ExamQuestion, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Option(models.Model):
    exam_question = models.ForeignKey(ExamQuestion, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['exam_question', 'is_correct']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**A `ExamQuestion`, can be related to a `Reply`, or to several `Option`s.**

This is my view:

```
@ajax_view
def get_exam_question(request, json_data):
    exam = Exam.objects.get(id = json_data['exam_id'])
    data = serializers.serialize("json", exam.examquestion_set.all())
    print(data)
    #for exam_question in exam.examquestion_set.all():
    return JsonResponse()
```

This is what prints the already serialized objects:

```
[{"model": "exam_system.examquestion", "pk": 2, "fields": {"exam": 10, "title": "Khe!", "created": "2020-06-29T02:07:21.347Z", "multiple_choice": false}}, {"model": "exam_system.examquestion", "pk": 3, "fields": {"exam": 10, "title": "KKKKK", "created": "2020-06-29T02:14:53.057Z", "multiple_choice": false}}, {"model": "exam_system.examquestion", "pk": 4, "fields": {"exam": 10, "title": "1111111111111", "created": "2020-06-29T02:17:13.248Z", "multiple_choice": false}}]
```

The only relationship that appears is with the model `Exam`. Is there a way that relations with `Reply` or `Option` can also appear? but it must be taken into account that a `ExamQuestion` can be related to either `Reply` or `Option`s, and a `ExamQuestion` cannot be related to both at the same time.

I tried to do something like this:

```
@ajax_view
def get_exam_question(request, json_data):
    exam = Exam.objects.get(id = json_data['exam_id'])
    questions = []

    for exam_question in exam.examquestion_set.all():
        question = serializers.serialize("json", exam_question)

        if hasattr(exam_question, 'reply'):
            reply = serializers.serialize("json", exam_question.reply)
            # relate reply to exam_question ???
            question['fields']['reply'] = reply

        elif hasattr(exam_question, 'option_set'):
            question['fields']['options'] = {}
            for option in exam_question.option_set.all():
                option = serializers.serialize("json", option)
                # relate option to exam_question ???
                question['fields']['options'].update(option)

        questions.append(question)

    return JsonResponse(questions) # ???
```

but I get this error (why does this happen?):

```
Internal Server Error: /manager/ajax/get_exam_question/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lcteen/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibme-2AdwtzpN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lcteen/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibme-2AdwtzpN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/lcteen/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibme-2AdwtzpN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lcteen/Documentos/Programming/Frameworks/Django/ibme/ibme/manager/views.py", line 328, in wrapper
    return view(request, json_data = json.loads(request.body))
  File "/home/lcteen/Documentos/Programming/Frameworks/Django/ibme/ibme/manager/views.py", line 351, in get_exam_question
    question = serializers.serialize("json", exam_question)
  File "/home/lcteen/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibme-2AdwtzpN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/lcteen/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibme-2AdwtzpN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 90, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
TypeError: 'ExamQuestion' object is not iterable
```

Also is the most optimal way to do it this way? or is there another more optimal way?

For example something like this?:

```
serializers.serialize("json", exam.examquestion_set.all(), fields = ('reply', 'option_set')) # ???
```

Any suggestion helps me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this (I'm not sure if it's the best way):

```
exam = Exam.objects.get(id = json_data['exam_id'])
questions = []

for exam_question in exam.examquestion_set.select_related():
    question = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", [exam_question]))[0]

    if hasattr(exam_question, 'reply'):
        question['fields']['reply'] = json.loads(
            serializers.serialize("json", [exam_question.reply], fields = ('text',))
        )[0]

    elif hasattr(exam_question, 'option_set'):
        question['fields']['options'] = []
        for option in exam_question.option_set.all():
            question['fields']['options'].append(
                json.loads(
                    serializers.serialize(
                        "json", [option], fields = ('text', 'is_correct')
                    )
                )[0]
            )

    questions.append(question)
```

If someone finds something more optimal I would appreciate it.